# MySQL Error code 1071 After applying multiple changes

Tags: php, laravel, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1071

I recently received a Lumen/Laravel project which came with an sql file created already by the other developers. While trying to set it up in my system(already set up the environment with the required configurations in MySQL workbench) I kept getting the error

```
Error Code: 1214. The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

In which apparently the fix lied in changing the datbase engine in the file from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM`.

After that change,  I made sure that the collation was set to the required one as specified in the file 
`COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

But when I try running the file I am now getting an error

`Error code: 1071. Specified key was too long: max key length is 1000 bytes`

The file is extremely long(so posting the entirety of the program here would make no sense besides not being rational to post 7000+ lines of sql) and was wondering if there was a simple solution to this. Some other answers here talk about changing individual lines of code in the creation of each table which would make no sense since everyone else is using this without issue(and even then my colleagues are clueless)

So, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I'm sure there is line information also so you can pinpoint which part is the culprit.

Comment: did you make all database connections correctly?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen referring to the particular line that causes the issue? let me update!

Comment: @Sachith everything had already been taken care of during the configuration of the .env file and additional Lumen config files as well as the set up of the localhost connection in workbench. Passwords and everything are in order.